# ¿Cómo hago para que me salga la respuesta de las operaciones aritméticas?

Tags: php, algoritmos

Llevo intentando que me de la respuesta de las operaciones pero no me sale, ya no sé que mas hacer, lo que me piden es lo siguiente:
*Cree una función llamada operaciones() que realice las operaciones
aritméticas básicas (suma, resta, multiplicación y división) entre dos
números, recibiendo como parámetros los dos datos sobre los que se
realizará la operación y un tercer parámetro que le indique a la función la
operación a realizar (diferente a los operadores del lenguaje, es decir, no se
puede usar: +,-,* ni /, podría ser: “S”, “R”, “M” y “D”, u otros que usted elija),
el parámetro de la operación es opcional y si lo deja vacío la suma debe
hacerse por defecto, la función debe seleccionar qué operación hacer,
ejecutarla y retornar el resultado.

*Almacene la función en un archivo llamado biblioteca.php y úsela (llámela)
en un archivo llamado index.php (por lo tanto, el archivo biblioteca.php debe
incluirse o requerirse desde dicho archivo).

El codigo lo llevo asi:

*Codigo index.php

```
<head>
<title>Operaciones basicas</title>
</head>
<script>
//verifica que solo puedan entrar numeros en el formulario
var a = window.Event ? true : false;
function soloNum(evt){    
var key = a ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;    
return (key <= 13 || (key >= 48 && key <= 57));
}
</script>

<?php 
require_once 'biblioteca.php';
?>
<p>Operaciones Basicas [S:+ R:- M:* D:/]</p>
<body>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="biblioteca.php">
<input type="text" name="primero" onkeypress="return soloNum(event)" />
<input type="text" name="operador" style="width:20px;" maxlength="1"/>
<input type="text" name="segundo" onkeypress="return soloNum(event)" />
<input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Resultado" />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

*codigo biblioteca.php

```
<?php
function operacion($num1,$num2,$operador='s'){
    switch ($operador) {
        case 's':
            $valor = $num1 + $num2;
            break;
        case 'r':
            $valor = $num1 - $num2;
            break;
        case 'm':
            $valor = $num1 * $num2;
            break;
        case 'd':
            $valor = $num1 / $num2;
            break;
    }
    return $valor;
}
```

Por favor, ayúdenme.

Comment: Deberías explicar mejor el problema que tienes con el código actual, lee [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo leer sobre los peticiones [POST](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.post.php) en PHP.

Dado que envías un formulario con el método POST, se espera que en tu archivo `biblioteca.php` captures los valores de dicho formulario. Pero obviamente dicho archivo no hace eso, ya que sólo contiene una función, por ello nos damos cuenta de que necesitamos agregar la lógica para eso. Esos datos se capturan mediante la variable `$_POST`.

Tu archivo archivo `biblioteca.php`:

```
<?php
    function operacion($num1,$num2,$operador='s'){
        switch ($operador) {
            case 's':
                $valor = $num1 + $num2;
                break;
            case 'r':
                $valor = $num1 - $num2;
                break;
            case 'm':
                $valor = $num1 * $num2;
                break;
            case 'd':
                $valor = $num1 / $num2;
                break;
        }
        return $valor;
    }

    // Capturas los valores del formulario
    $num1 = $_POST["primero"];
    $num2 = $_POST["segundo"];
    $operador = $_POST["operador"];

    // Usas el método dentro de tu biblioteca.php
    echo "El resultado es: " . operacion($num1,$num2,$operador);
```

El `require_once` que tienes en tu `index.php` no es necesario.

Comment: Ya he intentado con $_POST pero me salía error en esa línea. Es que lo he cambiado de tantas formas que ya ni sé que hacer. El resultado de la operación no me sale.

Comment: En qué línea tenías errro? Sólo es necesario que tengas 3 archivos para que funcione

Comment: El problema es que únicamente solo debo tener dos archivos uno llamado index.php y otro con biblioteca.php y el código que te mostré no me esta generando el resultado de la función.

Comment: Ya modifiqué mi respuesta. Pero hacerlo sólo con dos archivos no es bueno, ya que se supone que tu archivo "biblioteca" sólo debe tener funciones. Pero la lógica la tienes, ahora puedes modificar acorde a tus necesidades. Lee acerca de ello.